# Need visa for transit in Canada?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, canada

As a citizen of Argentina, I, in principle, need a visa to go to Canada, but not to most countries in Europe.

I am offered a ticket to Europe with a short layover in Canada (e.g. Vancouver).

1. Do I need a Canadian visa to be able to use that ticket?
2. I live in the US and have a greencard. Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Canada's visa tool](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) provides comprehensive information.

A citizen of Argentina would ordinarily need [a transit visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/apply.html), even for a short layover.

However, US permanent residents with valid green cards do not need a visa, [but only an eTA](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/apply.html) (Electronic Travel Authorization) to enter by air. You can apply for one online, and usually get an answer within minutes. When you fill out the eTA application, you'll be [asked](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/eta/english.pdf) if you're a US permanent resident, and if you answer yes, you'll be asked to supply the details from your green card.

Be sure to carry your green card with you when you travel.